# How can i add menu items to the context menu of a NSTextField

Tags: cocoa, nstextfield

I tried to overwrite the simple NSView method:

```
- (NSMenu *)menuForEvent:(NSEvent *)event {
   NSMenu* result = [super menuForEvent: event];
   NSMenuItem* mi = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle: @"Foobar" action: @selector(foobar) keyEquivalent: @""];
   [result addItem: mi];    
   return result;
}
```

but it does not work. It is never called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the text field has focus, I believe the menu you're getting is actually that of the [Field Editor](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/TextEditing/Tasks/FieldEditor.html). Maybe ask it for *its* menu.

Answer (score 5):

Try to use the NSTextViewDelegate Protocol

```
- (NSMenu *)textView:(NSTextView *)view menu:(NSMenu *)menu forEvent:(NSEvent *)event atIndex:(NSUInteger)charIndex
```

The window's field editor will then ask your NSTextField for the menu

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for others pointing the way. I haven't been able to get the window's default field editor to use any delegate methods. Finally I put the following in my window delegate's -windowDidLoad method

```
NSTextView* defaultFieldEditor = [self.window fieldEditor:YES forObject:nil];
//  defaultEditor.delegate = self; didn't help
NSMenu *mu = defaultEditor.menu;
[mu insertItem:[NSMenuItem separatorItem] atIndex:0];
[mu insertItemWithTitle:@"Insert Line"
                 action:@selector(acnInsertLine:)
          keyEquivalent:@"" atIndex:0];
 [mu insertItemWithTitle:@"Delete Line"
                  action:@selector(acnDeleteLine:)
           keyEquivalent:@"" atIndex:0];
```

This is supposed to put the items at the beginning (so reverse order). You could use `addItem:` instead. Both suffer from the problem that the contents of the menu vary and your items are likely to up somewhere in the middle.

Note that the field editor is a NSTextView even if the control it covers is a NSTextField. This has caused me some perplexity.